# Detecting “long objects” on overlapping images

Tags: deep-learning, image-processing, object-detection

I have a database of pictures of "long trucks" and I have to count, using some image recognition algorithm, the number of axles (how many tires the truck are using). In my database, instead of an image of the whole truck I have a sequence of overlapping pictures that gives me parts of the truck while driving on a lane.

Can someone give me any direction of papers, books, etc. that tackle the problem of object detection on overlapping images? I'm already searching for material, but indications would help me a lot.

Regards, LR

Comment: Is it a requirement that pictures of a truck remain separate? One could merge those pictures into one and then perform detection on it

Comment: Split the target function into subtasks and solve each after the other. First you can merge image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015341/how-to-combine-partially-overlapping-images-into-one-image and then you can try to detect the wheels using hough circle detection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254287/houghcircles-circle-detection-using-opencv-and-python - Although this is most certainly not the best way, this is a rather simple way. Try and then ask more questions regarding detail. I assume that this question will be closed because it is not related to statistics / too broad.